# Concat and Concat_ws in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database structure.

```
ID | Name | Marks
```

I am trying to insert records in my `PHP` script. If the record doesn't exist, I'm creating a new record. If it does exist, I'm concatenating the marks column with the new marks.

```
$strSQL = "Replace into student set ID = '".$id."', 
                 name = '".$name."', marks= CONCAT_WS(',',Marks,'".$marks."')";
```

The query is running fine but concat is not working. The old record is being overwritten by the new one. I tried `CONCAT` too.

Thanks

Comment: Don't create a comma-separated value column. You will regret it later when you need to report against this. Instead, create another table which stores `ID, Marks` one-to-many with your `student` table.

Comment: I see what you saying. I can have some other delimited like '|'.

Comment: Any delimiter is problematic. These belong in a separate normalized table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to handle this is with a separate normalized table holding student ids and marks.  Use `INSERT IGNORE` to insert the student info in to the `student` table, and then insert the marks into the `marks` table, multiple rows per student.  This also allows you to store a date along with each mark added to the table, or other information (like what course it belongs to).  Note that I wouldn't usually recommend using `INSERT IGNORE` to create a row, but instead check first in code if the row exists and only insert if it doesn't.

```
CREATE TABLE marks (
   markID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   studentID INT NOT NULL,
   mark VARCHAR() NOT NULL,
   markdate DATETIME NOT NULL
);

/* First execute the insert, which will ignore errors if it already exists */
INSERT IGNORE INTO student (ID, name) VALUES ($id, '$name');

/* Then insert the new marks. Loop to add as many new marks as needed */
INSERT INTO marks (studentID, mark, markdate) VALUES ($id, '$marks', NOW());
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I don't know how many marks per student are there. Student A might have 3 marks. In that case , I'd do A 2|3|4 and student B might have 2 marks. In that case I'll do B 2|3. (assuming '|' is the delimiter). Insert into will fail if I try to add more marks later..

Comment: I want to concatenate the marks column with new marks per student

Comment: @Ankur the point of the normalized table is that you can add as many as you need to add.  If you concatenate them, you will never be able to query effectively from the database. Instead you will be bound to having always to pull results with PHP and split the delimiter.

Comment: I see your point.. Thanks.. This helps.. I thought studentID is the primary key in marks table .. my bad !!

Comment: I put a surrogate key `markID` in as the PK. If you add a column for the course it belongs to, you could use a composite key of `(studentID, course, date)` but you might then want to use `DATE` instead of `DATETIME`.

Comment: yes..got your point...  Thanks for teaching me something here.. :-)